# conditions for something being being considered as a system?

Tags: definition, stability

without loss of generality can somebody answer the question in reference to a car being towed by a truck. I am asking this question because the work done by the truck on the car is different at different angles , and maybe that could cause a difference in velocities of the truck and car and thus instability.

Comment: *the work done by the truck on the car is different at different angles* - no it isn't. Remember that work is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{d}$ i.e. both the force and displacement are vectors.

Comment: A "system" is whatever we are trying to describe. There are no conditions (although some things may not be very useful to consider as systems on their own). I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: In general, if there are forces between two objects, they form a system.  If the forces are small enough, we can ignore them at first - decouple the objects - and see if the analysis is good enough.   For the tow truck example a lot depends upon how the two are connected - if it is essentially rigid then they will always travel at the same speed. But if it is just a loose chain (imagine a tug boat), then the coupling can support different speeds when starting and stopping.

Answer (score 1):

A *"system"* is an arbitrary selection of some part of the universe to consider distinct from the rest. There are no conditions beyond those that you impose.

A much more interesting question is how one picks a *useful* or *enlightening* system, and the answer to that depends on how you are going to use it it what you intend to achieve.

- **Do you want to learn something about the behavior of a particular object?** Consider that object as the system. Or perhaps that object and one or two other things that more with it.
- **Do you want to learn about the interaction of two (or more objects)?** Consider making them the system *or* drawing the dividing line between them (so that forces between them *don't* cancel internally).
- **Do you want to apply a conservation law?** Pick a system that is appropriately isolated (from net work for energy, from net impule for momentum and so on).
- and so on...

In short the decision about how to define "the system" in any particular consideration is part of your physics tool box and you will learn to do it mostly by experience and by observing how other have succeeded in the past.

If someone tells you that you have chosen the "wrong" system, they don't mean that there is a rule for which choice to make in this situation, they mean that they can see that the one you've selected isn't going to help you solve the problem in hand.